# Cancelling or revoking celery task in eventlet from django view

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet

I am trying revoke a celery task with following commands.

```
revoke('d9078da5-9915-40a0-bfa1-392c7bde42ed', terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')

revoke('d9078da5-9915-40a0-bfa1-392c7bde42ed', terminate=True)

revoke('d9078da5-9915-40a0-bfa1-392c7bde42ed')
```

None of which works, my worker pool is eventlet: Started with

```
$ celery -A scraper worker -P eventlet -c 1000 -l info
```

Please advise how to do this because i have a button in my django view which uses task I'd to cancel the task. There should be a way to do this but am not sure. With prefork pool it works.

```
[2015-10-26 09:07:38,411: ERROR/MainProcess] pidbox command error: NotImplementedError("<class 'celery.concurrency.eventlet.TaskPool'> does not implement kill_job",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 105, in dispatch
    reply = handle(method, kwdict(arguments))
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 126, in handle_cast
    return self.handle(method, arguments)
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 120, in handle
    return self.handlers[method](self.state, **arguments)
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/control.py", line 93, in revoke
    request.terminate(state.consumer.pool, signal=signum)
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/job.py", line 307, in terminate
    pool.terminate_job(self.worker_pid, signal)
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/base.py", line 116, in terminate_job
    '{0} does not implement kill_job'.format(type(self)))
NotImplementedError: <class 'celery.concurrency.eventlet.TaskPool'> does not implement kill_job
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message says that Celery's TaskPool (Eventlet compatible version) does not have this feature. So you can either implement it yourself and send patch to Celery team or just leave a feature request and wait.

It should be very easy to copy prefork TaskPool code and adapt it to Eventlet API, `greenthread.kill()`.